# Best introduction to recursive functions

Tags: reference-request, logic

Hello I'm looking for a solid introduction to recursive functions within the domain of mathematical logic. I'm studying logic and would like to become more informed about this area of theory. I would appreciate any suggested texts.

Comment: The classic (and still readable) book is Hartley Rodgers: Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I agree with your suggestion, but the author's name is Rogers not Rodgers.

Comment: You may consider also Piergiorgio Odifreddi, [Classical Recursion : Theory The theory of functions and sets of natural numbers Vol 1](http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Recursion-Theory-Foundations-Mathematics/dp/0444894837/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1402036272&sr=1-1&keywords=Piergiorgio+Odifreddi+Classical+Recursion+Theory+The+theory+of+functions+and+sets+of+natural+numbers) (2nd ed : 1992).

Answer (score 3):

If I had to choose just one book, then it would probably be

> Nigel Cutland, *Computability: An Introduction to Recursive Function Theory* (CUP 1980).

This is a rightly much-reprinted classic and is beautifully put together, even if (by now) perhaps just *slightly* old-school in "look-and-feel".

For more suggestions, you can take a look at The Teach Yourself Logic guide to the literature.

> http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic10-1.pdf

Check out §3.3 for introductory material on computable functions, and §5.5 for suggestions of rather more advanced texts.